# Dismiss UITextView in iOS when user clicks outside

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextview

In my iPhone app I have a UITextView added to my main view and I would like to dismiss it when user clicks anyplace in the screen outside of the UITextView boundaries.

Is it possible? What would be the best way to implement this?

Comment: Did this solve ur problem

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad{
    ....
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRec = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
        initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer: tapRec];
    ....
}

-(void)tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRec{
    [[self view] endEditing: YES];
}
```

You can also use i.e **optional**

```
 [textView resignFirstResponder];
```

In UITapGestureRecognizer

```
-(void)tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRec{
     [yourTextView resignFirstResponder];
    }
```

Or if it is required on **clicking next** then

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to turn your mainView into a UIControl.

[image]
[image]

```
-(IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender
{
    [[self view] endEditing:YES];
}
```